# Does Z+worldly cardinals fulfill Muller's criteria to found Mathematics?

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

Recall Muller's criteria in [Sets, Classes and Categories: page 14](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) for a theory that founds Mathematics.

> Arn't those captured simply by
> $$\sf Zermelo + \text {worldly cardinals exist} $$

define sets as classes with ranks lower than the first worldly cardinal and everything would go through!

A worldly cardinal is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa\models \sf ZFC$

Comment: You might be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375085/on-the-large-cardinals-foundations-of-categories

Comment: I see there is some difference between what the answer to your linked question is saying and what Muller is stating in his work. Unless I missed something, it is enough to just have POWERSET operator iterated upon a universe of sets to establish founding Cateorgies, powersets are not universes, and according to Muller we only need those iterated powers to be at FINITE distance from that universe. Now I don't know how to reconcile this with what the answer requires namely a countable sequence of UNIVERSES embedding seamelessly in an ascending order.